# How secure is NSUserDefaults when used to configure an Enterprise Application via an MDM?

Tags: ios, security, nsuserdefaults, mdm

I've been researching literacy about the secure aspect of the NSUserDefaults leveraged by the ManagedAppConfig capability of iOS.

We are leveraging this "new" iOS capability to configure our enterprise application via various MDM systems used in our customers landscape.

A debate is now raging on how secure it is.

From our side, the only way that we have found to get this information is to actually JailBrake the device. Which of course would be detected by the MDM system.

Any other security vulnerability that we may have missed there ? Anybody looked into the security aspect of this feature ?

Thanks!
Ingrid.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you store un `NSUserDefault` is easily accessible (with an app like iExplorer for mac, for example). No need to jailbreak. It is all stored in a .plist file in the Library/Preferences folder of your app.

I had to hide some information before, the way I did it was by using Data Encryption. For more information, read the section called [Enabling Data Protection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/AddingCapabilities/AddingCapabilities.html)

All you would need to do after enabling correct data protection, is to create a file and store your configuration there. By putting the Data Encryption to `NSFileProtectionComplete`, your file will be visible, put not readable when the device is locked. For this to work, the user must have set a password on his device